# Get the correct Hexadecimal for strange symbol

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have this strange symbol on my pl/sql developer client (check image it's the symbol between P and B )

[image]

In the past, and for a different symbol,  i was able to update my DB and remove them making this:

```
update table set ent_name = replace(ent_name, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW('C29B')), ' ');
```

The problem is that i dont remember how I translated the symbol (i had at that time) to the C29B.

Can you help me to understand how can i translate the currenct symbol to the HEX format, to i can use the command to remove it from my database?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like male sign [https://graphemica.com/%E2%99%82]
Is it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's in your table, you can use the `DUMP` function to find it.

Use `DUMP` to get the byte representation of the data in code of you wish to inspect for weirdness.

A good overview: [Oracle / PLSQL: DUMP Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/dump.php)

Here's some text with plain ASCII:

`select dump('Dashes-and "smart quotes"') from dual;`

> Typ=96 Len=25:
>   68,97,115,104,101,115,45,97,110,100,32,34,115,109,97,114,116,32,113,117,111,116,101,115,34

Now introduce funny characters:

`select dump('Dashes—and “smart quotes”') from dual;`

> Typ=96 Len=31:
>   68,97,115,104,101,115,226,128,148,97,110,100,32,226,128,156,115,109,97,114,116,32,113,117,111,116,101,115,226,128,157

In this case, the number of bytes increased because my DB is using `UTF8`. Numbers outside of the valid range for ASCII stand out and can be inspected further.

The `ASCIISTR` function provides an even more convenient way to see the special characters:

`select asciistr('Dashes—and “smart quotes”') from dual;`

> Dashes\2014and \201Csmart quotes\201D

This one converts non-ASCII characters into backslashed Unicode hex.

The `DUMP` function takes an additional argument that can be used to format the output in a nice way:

`select DUMP('Thumbs ', 1017) from dual;`

> Typ=96 Len=11 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: T,h,u,m,b,s, ,f0,9f,91,8d

`select DUMP('Smiley  Face', 17) from dual;`

> Typ=96 Len=16: S,m,i,l,e,y, ,f0,9f,98,8a, ,F,a,c,e